# Sorting on Group in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have report that based on the Createdon date group and its amount on that.so I have created group on createdon in SSRS Report and also put sorting based on createdon date.The data is like this

```
Date                Total Amount
6-22-2013             500
5-23-2013             500
5-24-2013             1000
5-28-2013             200
6-21-2013             300
6-23-2013             400
```

I shown you some of the data.same way that are lots of data and every data shown as expected.but expect the one data as you can see the first record regarding 6-22-2013.It should be come second last based on group as i sort group based on Createdon date.I feel that this bug is from Microsoft.However I am not sure but how can only one record created this problem?Any help from anybody would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the date field is actually date. I mean if it is text then it will be sorted arbitrarly .

Comment: Yes I have checked.I have created one calculated field called custDate =cDate(FormatDateTime(Fields!createdon.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate)) and based on this I have sort the group based on this custDate field

Comment: I would advise doing your date format conversions in the DB layer, then make sure the column's Data Type is one of the `DATETIME` variations. Then it should sort appropriately in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting by below expressions

=day(Fields!createdon.Value)-- 1st sort expression

=month(Fields!createdon.Value)--2nd sort expression

=Year(Fields!createdon.Value)-- 3rd sort expression